# How set React Component on onClick() event inside div-element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, react-component

I have one React PureComponent which makes some fetch and after return a `table(list of div's)` of div-elements. Each `div` has inside some span elements.

Also, I have another React Component which must open some HTML elements.

I want to set 2nd React Component on `onClick()` event for each `div` element from the 1st React PureComponent. So in the ideal situation, it must open me some kin of modal page when I will click on `div` element.

Now it looks like that nothing happened when I click on `div` element

1st PureComponent

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from "../components/modal/form";

let test = {};

const PATH_BASE = "my url which works fine";

console.log("1st try Actions");
const i = 10;

class Actions extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      result: null,
      show: false
    };
    this.setSearchTopStories = this.setSearchTopStories.bind(this);
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
  }
  showModal = e => {
    this.setState({
      show: !this.state.show
    });
  };
  setSearchTopStories(result) {
    this.setState({ result });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${PATH_BASE}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => this.setSearchTopStories(result))

      .catch(error => error);
  }
  render() {
    const { searchTerm, result } = this.state;
    console.log("* Actions Pure*");
    console.log(result);
    console.log("=");

    return (
      <div>
        {result !== null
          ? result.map((item, index) => (
              <div
                onClick={() => (
                  <Modal onClose={this.showModal} show={this.state.show}>
                    Mdl--
                  </Modal>
                )}
              >
                <span>{item.name}</span>
                <span>{item.amount}</span>
              </div>
            ))
          : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Actions;
```

2nd Component

```
import React from "react";
import Actions from "../../data/Actions";

export default class Modal extends React.Component {
  onClose = e => {
    this.props.onClose && this.props.onClose(e);
  };
  render() {
    console.log("KLICK");
    if (!this.props.show) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={e => {
              this.onClose(e);
            }}
          >
            Close
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass click handler to the child.

modal component

```
export class ModalComponent extends Component {
  handleChange = e => {
    // do something within component first
    console.log("clicked inside Modal component");

    // do something from parent
    this.props.handleClickFromParent(e, this.props.id);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button id="demo" onClick={this.handleChange}>
          click me {this.props.id}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Actions component

```
export class ActionsComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    clicked: 0
  };

  handleClickFromParent = (event, id) => {
    console.log(event, id);
    const clicked = id;
    this.setState({
      clicked
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ModalComponent
          id={1}
          handleClickFromParent={this.handleClickFromParent}
        />
        <ModalComponent
          id={2}
          handleClickFromParent={this.handleClickFromParent}
        />
        {this.state.clicked}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-morning-gqtiz

Comment: but when i try to send input argument to ModalComponent from ActionsComponent and i dint see this parametrs in `this.props`

Comment: what do you mean by `this  parameters`? the props I mentioned e.g. `handleClickFromParent` is not out of the box. when I declare `<ModalComponent
          handleClickFromParent={...}
        />` then it become available in ModalComponent as a a prop. It doesn't have to be `handleClickFromParent` it can be anything you decide to call it.